# Scroll to top of page before Link route change in NextJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, scroll, next.js

When I click a link to a new page the page loads and then scrolls to the top of the page. I'd like to change this behavior that the scroll resets to the top of the page before the route change is rendered. You can see the behavior at https://mitconsulting.group/ if you scroll down on the home page and then use the navbar to navigate to a new page without scrolling back up, the new page renders and then scrolls to the top. This messes up my fade-in scroll animations and generally looks bad.

Comment: That's not the default for a Next.js app, did you add the `scroll-behavior: smooth` styling anywhere in the app? Removing it would prevent the scroll animation.

Comment: Maybe you can use [next/router, routeChangeStart event](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerevents), e.g.: `router.events.on( 'routeChangeStart', () => { /* scroll to top */ } );`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using react-bootstrap, like I was, you'll need to override the `scroll-behavior: smooth;` with `scroll-behavior: auto !important;`

Comment: Works like a charm. Putting this at `:root {}` css selector does the trick.